# Добавить кнопки на заголовок группы в UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Друзья, пытаюсь сделать кастомный заголовок для таблицы, однако столкнулся с проблемой:
лэйбл добавляется с легкостью, а вот кнопка как бы есть (вызывается метод при нажатии) но ее не видно. Максимум чего я смог добиться это изменить цвет при помощи

```
[checkButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

В этом случае видно, где кнопка, но пикчи не ставятся на фон, не ставятся заголовки... 
Может кто может что подсказать, был бы очень благодарен

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[titleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UILabel *titleName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 14, 280, 21)];
titleName.text = @"someName";

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"textbutton_medium.png"];

UIButton *checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 43, 144, 47)];
[checkButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
checkButton.titleLabel.text = @"someText";

[checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkInterestsInSectionAction:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[titleView addSubview:titleName];
[titleView addSubview:checkButton];

return titleView;
```

}

Comment: Поропбуйте 

    UIButton *checkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 43, 144, 47)];

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло, а помогла загрузка с nib'a:

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    
    NSArray         *tableViewViewObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View"
                                                                         owner:self
                                                                       options:nil];
    
    titleView = tableViewViewObject[0];
    

return titleView;

Comment: Проверьте, верно ли названа картинка, которую вы кладете как backgroundImage.

Answer (score 1):

вместо

```
setBackgroundImage:forState:
```

используйте

```
setImage:forState:
```